# Invalid value for property 'Filename'. Unexpected file extension: webmanifest. Expecting: gif

Tags: multimedia, sites-9.5

We are using SDL Tridion Sites 9.5. I m trying to create New multimedia component which has file extension and *.ico and *.webmanifest file. I have added corresponding Multimedia type in CMS but when trying to save components I m getting below error

```
Invalid value for property 'Filename'. Unexpected file extension: webmanifest. Expecting: gif.


Component: Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService
Errorcode: 839
User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

StackTrace Information Details:
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.BinaryContent.AssertValidProperties(IEnumerable`1 allowedMultiMediaTypes, Boolean changedToInternalBinaryContent)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Component.OnSaving(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.Save(Boolean checkInAfterSave)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceBase.Create(IdentifiableObjectData data, ReadOptions readBackOptions)
   at SyncInvokeCreate(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

[image]

Comment: Abdul , also let us know did you do a fresh install of Sites 9.5 or you did a upgrade from older version

Comment: Abdul  , may be you have uploaded a wrong file , can you try to uplaod the file  again and select the file type manually and see when you try to add the MM to the component it will save properly.  the MM field is part of meta data.

Answer (score 5):

Abdul , make sure you add the mime type to the Allowed Multimedia type

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have forgotten to add New MIME Types into Allowed Multimedia types.

Comment: Great hope it helped